# Command/script to extract "sub-tarball" from tarball

Tags: tar

I am aware of that I can extract single/multiple files from a tar archive, but is there a command that I can easily pass to immediately create a "sub-tarball" from an existing tar archive? This is because some tarballs are too large do this

```
Extract one by one -> Tar with --delete-files option
```

Answer (score 0):

First, extract the file  from the archive. Then to delete the file, `tar` has a `--delete` option which will delete a file from the archive:

```
tar xf tar-file file-to-extract
tar f tar-file --delete file-to-extract
```